# Invalid property [enableActionsInNative] in component [force:highlightsPanel] when deploying

Tags: deployment, highlights-panel

Came across these two errors when deploying my first change set.

I've read another thread where it says to delete your highlights panel, but I'm not sure how to do that. Do I delete the highlights panel in my sandbox then send it to deployment? Or do I delete the highlights panel on my production org then deploy? Or both?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I have also faced the similar issue. In my case, there was a mismatch between name space of my Develoment org and metadata (lighting page).

Answer (score 0):

I also have faced this error/problem. I have resolved this error by removing the lightning record page from the object.

Steps to remove the lightning record page:

1. Go to object ex. Account
2. From left side panel click on the Lightning Record Pages
3. Remove/Delete all the Lightning record pages
   Note:- You will not be able to delete the record page if it is currently assigned to org default/app default/app record type and profile -

[image: see image] To delete this first remove the page assignment :- click- page name:*Record_Page -> Edit ->Activation -> Remove as .. ->select appropriate option-> Next -> Save

4. Save
5. Delete this record page
6. Then deploy your change set to the target Organization

Thanks.